# Use input as basis of what date to display

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need a way to use the input on a userform to determine the date that will be displayed on the output. Here's my code:

```
If StatusBox.Value <= "23:59" And ShiftCode.Value = "AP" Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = ((Date - 1) + " " + StatusBox.Value + " " + "CEST")
Else
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = (Date + " " + StatusBox.Value + " " + "CEST")
End If
```

Basically I need the date to be displayed as `Date - 1` when the input from StatusBox.Value is less than or equal to `11:59 PM or 23:59` the inputs on the `StatusBox` field will always be in the 12-Hour format.

Comment: Does that code not work?

Comment: It does not work with the if statement, but if i remove it, it works.

Comment: the time is always going to be less than 23:59. them minute after that, it's going to be 00:00, which is also less than 23:59.  You will need to work out some other logic to decide if you need to take a day off

Comment: @SeanC that's what I've been thinking about. Isn't there a way to declare the input as `"Time"` in VBA?

Comment: What if you took the left part of the time and the right part, and compared them? I.e. 23:59 - compare the 23 against 24 (being midnight), and the 59 against 00?   And @SeanC - I need to take a day off, my own logic says so! :P

Comment: @BruceWayne and how do you propose I do that? By putting them in an array? I'm actually thinking of putting the string 23:00 to 23:59 in an array(59) and compare them with 00:00 (12:00 AM) via for loop. Do you think this would work?

Comment: what about deciding when you should **not** take a day off, and compare that instead?

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes the following:

- `StatusBox.Value` is an Excel serial number formatted with a time format *(no Date included)* , as such `StatusBox.Value` is a decimal number with a value ranging from `0` *(zero)* to `0.99988426`, representing the times from `0:00:00` *(12:00:00 AM)* to `23:59:59` *(11:59:59 P.M.)*. Therefore when this serial number reaches the 24 hours becomes `1` (one).

Based on the above replace this:

`If StatusBox.Value <= "23:59"` ...

with this

`If StatusBox.Value <= 1` ...

However if `StatusBox.Value` includes an `[expected Date value]` then use this  as replacement line:

`If StatusBox.Value <= [expected Date value]` ...

[image]

Comment: looks awesome, will try this when I get home and let you know how it goes